# Cannot set properties of null (setting 'data') en DataTable con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy tratando de hacer una data table con la información que me devuelve un endpoint, luego de hacerle fetch, quiero que se llene la datatable con la información que obtuvo. Sin importar que, siempre me devuelve el mismo error de `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'data')` y una advertencia de `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'data') TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'data')` y honestamente con JQuery soy relativamente nuevo, y por mas que busco, no encuentro a que o porque es el error. Mi .js

```
const url = "https://my_endpoint.com/parameters?u=u&t=t";
await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
})
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);        
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#referred').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "responsive": true,
                //"data": data, No estoy seguro porque me marca error, ya que algunas veces de prueba, nisiquiera le pongo este parametro
                'columns': [ //Solo quiero mostrar dos elementos de los que me devuelven, siendo...
                    { 'Fecha de Inscripción': 'Date', },
                    {  'Nombre': 'DisplayName', },
                ]
            });
        } );
    })
    .catch(err => { console.error('Error! =>', err) });
```

Y en mi .html

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>

<table id="referred" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fecha de Inscripción</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Cuando le pones la opcion serverSide:True a un datatable, necesitas poner donde va a hacer el ajax con la opcion 'ajax: tu_url' esta debe de regresar el array de las filas ya formateadas https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side . por eso da ese error.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, te hace falta la etiqueta tbody en tu tabla

```
<table id="referred" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fecha de Inscripción</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Lo segundo es que cuando le pones la opcion serverSide a el datatable, este espera que le des una url a donde va a ir a preguntar por los dato. de tal manera que deberia de quedar como:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#referred').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "responsive": true,
      "ajax": "https://my_endpoint.com/parameters?u=u&t=t",
      'columns': [
        { 'Fecha de Inscripción': 'Date', },
        { 'Nombre': 'DisplayName', },
      ]
    });
  });
```

En lugar de que lo hagas por fetch, esta ya generara la peticion, o si lo haces por fetch simplemente quita la opcion de serverSide:True y llenas con data como ya lo haces.

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer de la forma en que me indicas, pero sigue sin devolver nada. Incluso encontré esta forma `        "ajax": {
            "url": "https://my_endpoint.com/parameters?u=u&t=t",
            "type": "GET",
            "dataSrc": "",
            "dataType": "json"
        },` pero nada

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero no puede ser porque ajax no usa un tipo `await` como lo hace el fetch??

Comment: Puedes quitar el ajax del datatable y hacerlo con el fetch, solo quita la opcion "serverSide": true, y en el data pon tu resultado